# What is the most elegant way to call an event of another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have a Form called `Form1` which will somehow (how is not relevant) calls another form `Form2`

(Form1)

```
Form2 f2= new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();
```

This `Form2` has a button that will do *some operation* everytime the user clicks on this button.

However, I want that *the first time* i.e. when Form2 is just shown, the code in the button (*some operation*) gets executed.

In other words I have to be able to call the code in Form2's `button_Click` which is private.

Now I can think of some ways to make this possible(making the click event public etc) , but my question is what is the most elegant (or correct) way to do this?

Comment: If worst comes to worst, make it public... Sorted... However i would consider a more modern approach of decoupled messaging

Comment: Yes, I have thought of that. But I am wondering if there are better ways to accomplish that

Comment: Making it public, is not a good Idea. for single run you can add an static boolean flag in `Form2` to show that you have executed it before

Comment: you can move the lines of `button_Click` to a new accessible method and invoke that new method on `button_Click` and wherever you want.

Comment: @RezaNoei If a `static` flag is used, then you could not have multiple instances of that form displayed at the same time. Generally, a member flag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is just make it public, however its not the bastion of great design.

Decoupled messaging is probably where you want to be, [event aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) or any pub sub method messaging system. This is a more modern and scalable approach, the participants need not know about each other allowing you to make the methods private and giving you a more maintainable [decoupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) solution, and keep your classes self consistent.

*Unity*, *MvvmLight* both have these sorts of messaging systems, however there are lots of them.

**Example of how this might work**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventPublisher.Instance.Subscribe<NewUserCreated>
        (n => listBoxUsers.Items.Add(n.User.Name));
}

...

// some other class
private void Form2()
{

    var user = new User()
               {
                   Name = textBoxUserName.Text,
                   Password = textBoxPassword.Text,
                   Email = textBoxEmail.Text
               };
    EventPublisher.Instance.Publish(new NewUserRequested(user));
}
```

Comment: While public access is bad, a messaging system is probably overkill for many applications where you have only a few very specific interactions between specific forms… So in my answer, I gave a simple alternative that works well in those cases. Your solution would still be preferred in a system where there might be many source of changes.

Comment: @Phil1970 yeah sure, ill upvote as your answer is worthy, well read, and simple for new developers to understand

Answer (score 2):

I would add a property to `Form2` to tell the form I like to automatically executed an action.

```
class Form2
{
    public bool AutoExecuteSomeOperation { get; set; }
}
```

In `Form1`, you would set that property and in `Form2` you would check and execute appropriate code if the property was set.

I would recommend that you refactor `button_Click` to call another method which you can also call for automatic execution. I like to keep event handler simple and executed only for the event on the control that served to name the event handler. Thus, you know that `button_Click` is an handler for a `Click` event on a control named `button`. It makes the code easier to maintain.

You can decide if you want to reset the property once the code is executed or you can add some validation that the property changes are valid. For exemple, you might want to ensure that the property is called before displaying the form.

In all cases, you should avoid having any reference to a control from an external form. Only `Form1` itself should know that it contains a button. Any use from outside world should be done through a public property or public event of the form. That way, if you decide that the button should be replaced by an hyperlink, a menu item, a checkbox or anything else `Form1` does not need to be updated. This is very similar to what should be done for `UserControl`. The less internal details leak, the easier it will be to make internal changes without having to update all caller.

Answer (score 2):

Move the code from the OnClick event into its own method (e.g. "DoWork"), then call that method from the OnClick event.

Either call it when you create the form

```
var frm = new demoForm();
frm.DoWork();
frm.Show();
```

Or call it in the forms constructor.

```
public partial class demoForm : Form {
        public demoForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoWork();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            DoWork();
        }
        public void DoWork() {
            //Code here
        }
    }
```